# How to get the current weights of a chain for all extrinsics to verify all benchmarks has been integrated?

Tags: parachain, runtime, benchmarking, weight

I have just ran benchmarks and updated all the weights of the pallets in my parachain... or have I?

How can I verify that all my changes "bite"?
Is there a way to check the weights of a running chain and detect if some extrinsics still evaluates to the default e.g. `10_000`?

*Included the parachain tag, I'm not sure if that is important.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`queryInfo`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#queryinfoextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-runtimedispatchinfo) RPC enpoint to get weight of a particular extrinsic.

Comment: This returns *summary: Retrieves the fee information for an encoded extrinsic* witch is close but it is not practical to use for this.

Comment: @Simson, check the full context for this answer, https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11819 I do feel that it could be helpful for your scenario

Comment: @Simson I believe it contains weight as one of the fields of the returned struct. [See the code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/2b2bad672592b9a1ee8029104afce7b482068705/packages/types/src/interfaces/payment/types.ts#L22)

Answer (score 1):

A `Call` itself does not have a *weight* but only a *weight annontation* in the form of `#[pallet::weight(…)]`.
A `Dispatchable`, which is a combination of a `Call` and its encoded arguments, has a concrete weight since the weight can depend on the arguments.
The difference is that this a `Call` has a formula with variables as weight, not a constant.
So you cannot say how much concrete weight a call has. Further to this the benchmarking functions do not always 1:1 map to calls, which makes it more difficult to compare.

SWC https://github.com/ggwpez/substrate-weight-compare (eg deployed to https://weights.tasty.limo/compare-mr) can compare this if you set the *Evaluation Method* to `Base` which will set all possible components to zero and calculate the concrete value per `Call`.
However it does this on a source-code level, not a WASM runtime blob or running RPC node.
It could therefore still happen that you just forget to use the weights in the runtime file.